# Spring 3.1.3 common model

Tags: java, spring, model

I'm developing a web page using spring 3.1.3 framework and I want to set a counter (number of registers counter) in all pages but I don't want to put in every get method this counter. There is any other way like a common model to set once and don't worry about this counter in any other page (and new pages also)??

Thanks

Comment: You should show what have you tried.

Comment: I only tried controller advice, but this is only for spring versions greatest than mine and I cannot update the spring version.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution right under my nose in here: [Add attributes to the model of all controllers in Spring 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360784/add-attributes-to-the-model-of-all-controllers-in-spring-3?rq=1)

Is perfect!!;)

Thanks anyway!